# Sphinx: what exactly does indexer --merge do?

Tags: sphinx

Sphinx manual [says](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#index-merging) that index merging should keep old keywords along with new ones:

> Note, however, that the "old" keywords will not be automatically removed in such cases. For example, if there's a keyword "old" associated with document 123 in DSTINDEX, and a keyword "new" associated with it in SRCINDEX, document 123 will be found by both keywords after the merge.

I cannot reproduce this.

1. We have a document with id 1 and text 'one' in index `main`
2. Text in the DB table changes from 'one' to 'two'
3. `indexer --rotate delta`
4. `indexer --rotate --merge main delta`
5. Wait for `searchd` to reload the index
6. Now we can find document 1 by `SELECT id FROM main WHERE match('two')`, but `match('one')` does not find anything.

Sources for both indexes are defined essentially as:

```
sql_query = SELECT id, text FROM tbl
```

I have also tried to specify keywords via `sql_joined_field` and merge does not keep old keywords from it too.

Does this mean the manual is wrong? Is it safe to assume that if SRCINDEX has info for an ID (attributes and text keywords), merge process will discard everything DSTINDEX had for that ID and replace it with new info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked Andrey Aksenoff (creator of Sphinx) about this. He said that now they clean duplicate id while merging if index docinfo is extern.

So yes, it is a bug in documentation.

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I was hoping for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If Sphinx found duplicate IDs when they are eliminated from search results, so you Sphinx return only unique IDs.
What's why you didn't see them in search results.

Comment: What do you mean, duplicate IDs where? When merging? So the manual is wrong?

Comment: You said you have id 1 in both indexes main and delta, so after merging delta into main you will have duplicate ID 1 in the main index. But, when you perform the search duplicate ID eliminated by Sphinx, so you see only one result found for id 1. Manual is not wrong. :)

Comment: It seems we're talking about different things here. Of course I wouldn't expect the same id returned twice. The problem is I don't see any results at all when I search for the old keyword.

Comment: Yes, you right. It is a bug or documentation should be updated to new behaviour of indexer merge.